# NightwatchJS .waitForElementPresent abortOnFailure not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, automated-tests, nightwatch.js

I'm using NightwatchJS with NodeJS: http://nightwatchjs.org/api

I have a modal dialog, which may or may not appear. It has a `#close_button` that needs to be clicked (if the modal does appear) to continue.

I set the `abortOnFailure` parameter of `waitForElementPresent` to `false` so the script continues if the modal does not appear. However I can't get it to work.

Any suggestions?

```
module.exports = {
    "Test" : function (browser) {
        browser
            .url("http://domain.com/")
            .waitForElementPresent('#close_button', 5000, false, function() {
                this.click('#close_button')
            })
            .setValue('#username', 'test@email.com')
            //more code here
            .end(); //does end() go here or inside .waitForElementPresent() above?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`abortOnFailure` works fine, however `waitForElementPresent` has a bug now in which the callback you passed it's not called in the correct context. That will be fixed.

In the mean time you can write your test like this, with placing the `click` outside, which is the same thing and looks cleaner:

```
module.exports = {
  "Test" : function (browser) {
    browser
      .url("http://domain.com/")
      .waitForElementPresent('#close_button', 5000, false)
      .click('#close_button')
      .setValue('#username', 'test@email.com')
      //more code here
      .end(); // end() goes here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into something similar, I was waiting for an iframe to be present. I created a function to actually close it:

pageObject function:

```
Home.prototype.closeIframe = function(browser) {
var self = this;
console.log('Checking for iframe');
this.browser
        .isVisible(iframeSelectors.iframe, function(result) {
            if (result.value === true) {
                self.browser
                        .log('iframe visible')
                        .frame(iframeSelectors.name)
                        .waitForElementVisible(iframeSelectors.closeLink)
                        .click(iframeSelectors.closeLink)
                        .assert.elementNotPresent(iframeSelectors.iframe)
                        .frame(null)
                        .pause(2000); //allow for proper frame switching
            } else {
                console.log('iframe is not visible');
            }
        });

return this;
```

In my test I wait for the page to fully load before executing the above function.